# Why scala cannot infer common return type for a function with multiple parameter lists?

Tags: scala

Scala can infer the common base of the two parameters to a function, `T = Option[Int]` is found from `Some[Int]` and `None`:

```
  def handleUndefined1[T](op: => T, alt: => T) : T = {
    try { op }
    catch { case _: Exception => alt }
  }

  val x = handleUndefined1(Some(1),None)  // Option[Int]
```

But as a partial function:

```
  def handleUndefined2[T](op: => T)(alt: => T) : T = {
    try { op }
    catch { case _: Exception => alt }
  }

  // None is not Some[Int]      
  val x = handleUndefined2(Some(1))(None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not a "partial function" what you're doing is called a "curried function."

Second, try the following:

```
val x = handleUndefined1(Some(1), _)
```

and see what happens. You'll get a warning saying that you're missing a type parameter on the 2nd parameter. Why?

The type inferencer goes from left to right. Generally, types in the first argument group will determine those in the 2nd, 3rd, etc. If you leave out a type parameter, the inferencer will not be able to determine the type it should become as you've left out information.

Answer (score 2):

Use Option rather than Some:

```
val x = handleUndefined2(Option(1))(None)
```

Alternatively you can coerce the Some to Option:

```
val x = handleUndefined2(Some(1): Option[Int])(None)
```

*Generally it's a good idea to always use Option rather than Some for this reason.*

Comment: I don't know about your general advice (in the sense that I like most-specific type that makes sense), but you hit this with the signature for folds, where the neutral or zero element must have the correct type.

Comment: `handleUndefined2[Option[Int]](Some(1))(None)` is another option.

Comment: @som-snytt I think Odersky mentioned this advice in the FP Scala Coursera course, but perhaps it was someone else...

Comment: The other common gotcha is overriding `def f: Option[A]` with `def f = Some(a)` as that narrows inferred type of f (tho' that's considered a bug now and will change). You're probably right about the rule.

Comment: @som-snytt Ah, now I remember, another difference is `Some(null: String)` vs `Option(null: String)`... almost always you want the `Option` behavior (`None`).

Comment: Someone just got it the other way around: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5277#issuecomment-232565307